# JavaScript get visible HTML5 notifications

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, notifications

Basically, I need to verify whether HTML5 notifications arrive or not.

I know that there is currently no support in Selenium for any interaction with HTML5 notifications, so I want to use `JavascriptExecutor` to try at least parsing information from them, if any.

Notifications API provides idea only how to post notifications and `Notifications.onshow` gives possibility to do something when notification we know about is shown, which is not my case.

Is there any known way to read content from all currently visible HTML5 notifications using JavaScript?